# Incorrect Rake version found when installing Gitlab 6.7

Tags: ruby, rake, bundler, gitlab

I am trying to install Gitlab 6.7 on Amazon Linux 2014.03, which is similar to CentOS/RHEL. I've followed the CentOS instructions and I get this error in the ["Initialize Database and Activate Advanced Features"](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/tree/master/install/centos#initialize-database-and-activate-advanced-features) section:

```
$ sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production
Could not find rake-10.1.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

It looks like the version of rake is different but I followed all of the instructions to build Ruby from source.

```
$ sudo -u git -H rake --version
rake, version 0.9.6
```

I'm not familiar with ruby or bundle, so I ran "bundle install" as the error message suggested, but afterwards, I see the same issue.

```
$ sudo -u git -H bundle install | grep rake
Using rake 10.1.1
$ sudo -u git -H bundle install | tail -3
Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the groups development, test, postgres and aws were not installed.
It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that Amazon Linux has a separate package called ruby20 installed:

```
$ sudo yum list installed | grep ruby
ruby20.x86_64                        2.0.0.451-1.14.amzn1          installed    
ruby20-irb.noarch                    2.0.0.451-1.14.amzn1          installed    
ruby20-libs.x86_64                   2.0.0.451-1.14.amzn1          installed    
rubygem20-bigdecimal.x86_64          1.2.0-1.14.amzn1              installed    
rubygem20-json.x86_64                1.7.7-101.27.amzn1            @amzn-updates
rubygem20-psych.x86_64               2.0.0-1.14.amzn1              installed    
rubygem20-rdoc.noarch                4.0.1-2.18.amzn1              @amzn-main   
rubygems20.noarch                    2.0.14-1.14.amzn1             installed
```

Ran the following and then everything worked:

```
$ sudo yum remove ruby20 ruby20-libs
```